# Passing cookies in NodeJs http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm kind of a newbie in NodeJs. I'm trying to make an http request and pass a cookie. I've read all the threads on stackoverflow about it and made up a piece of code that should theoretically work. But, it doesn't.

What I'm trying to do is to send a cookie with the store code to one online-shop which will show me the information about this very shop. If there is no cookie it shows the default `div` asking to choose a shop.

Here is my code:

```
var request = require('request'),
    http = require('follow-redirects').http,
    request = request.defaults({
        jar: true
    });

var cookieString = 'MC_STORE_ID=66860; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86409000);
var str = '';
//var uri = 'example.de';

//var j = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie(cookieString);
j.setCookie(cookie, uri);

var options = {
    hostname: 'example.de',
    path: '/pathexample',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
            'Cookie': cookie,
            'Accept': '/',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    //,jar: j
};

http.request(options, function (resp) {
    resp.setEncoding('utf8');
    console.log(resp.headers);
    if (resp.statusCode) {
        resp.on('data', function (part) {
            str += part;
        });
        resp.on('end', function (part) {
            console.log(str);
        });

        resp.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
        });
    }
}).end(str);
```

I assume that the cookie will be sent and accepted with my request, but it isn't. I've also tried `jar`. I commented it out in the code. But, it seems not to work for me either. When I do `console.log(resp.headers)` I see the original cookies, but not mine. Can someone give me a hint?

The cookie structure is correct. When I run `document.cookie=cookie;` in google chrome console it is succsessfuly replaced.

Comment: What is request module ? https://github.com/mikeal/request ?

Comment: yes, exactly this one

Answer (score 19):

In your headers try to put directly the cookieString

```
headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Cookie': cookieString,
    'Accept': '/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
```

Comment: For some reason "Cookie" header works perfectly but "cookie" option seems not work in request nor jsdom.  Strange.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, @Ricardo helped me to figure out.
I have removed the **jar** key from header

```
//Set the cookie instead of setting into header
var cookie = request.cookie('MC_STORE_ID=66860');


// Set the headers for the request
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data),
    'Cookie': cookie
};
// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: requestObj["URL"],
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
};

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        cb(null, {status: 0, statusDsc: "success", data: body});
    } else {
        cb(error, {status: 2, statusDsc: JSON.stringify(error)});
    }
});
```

This is kind of mix between your cookie data and my **request** function.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I didn't realize you have to do `var cookie = request.cookie('MC_STORE_ID=66860');`. I was just doing `var headers = { 'Cookie': rawCookieStr };`

Answer (score 4):

Your variable *cookieString* is a *Set-Cookie* header. It's a server header that the server sends to the client but not a cookie that the client sends to the server.

*Set-Cookie* header :

```
 MC_STORE_ID=66860; expires=1234;
```

The client sends in *Cookie* Header this:

```
 MC_STORE_ID=66860;
```

Try these functions :

```
function dataCookieToString(dataCookie) {
    var t = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < dataCookie.length; x++) {
        t += ((t != "") ? "; " : "") + dataCookie[x].key + "=" + dataCookie[x].value;
    }
    return t;
}

function mkdataCookie(cookie) {
    var t, j;
    cookie = cookie.toString().replace(/,([^ ])/g, ",[12],$1").split(",[12],");
    for (var x = 0; x < cookie.length; x++) {
        cookie[x] = cookie[x].split("; ");
        j = cookie[x][0].split("=");
        t = {
            key: j[0],
            value: j[1]
        };
        for (var i = 1; i < cookie[x].length; i++) {
            j = cookie[x][i].split("=");
            t[j[0]] = j[1];
        }
        cookie[x] = t;
    }

    return cookie;
}
```

To start use this :

```
dataCookie = mkdataCookie('MC_STORE_ID=66860; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86409000));
// or mkdataCookie(resp.headers["set-cookie"]) in your `http.request.end()` function.
```

`mkdataCookie` returns an object.

Then you can set it in your header:

```
headers: {
    "User-Agent": "NodeJS/1.0",
    "Cookie": dataCookieToString(dataCookie)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand what I was doing wrong. 
Just one more question: data.length in the header suppose to be dataCookieToString(dataCookie).length or what is "data"? I was trying to set it like this but the script is just hänging without a response.

Comment: Sorry bad copy/past. (Content-Length, is length of data that you send with the POST request).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately both answers didn't work for me. I will repeat that the aim was to make a http request with passing a cookie containing the store code. To get the pages HTML for this very branch, not the standars page asking me to pick one.
After trying both options I didn't get any error, but also it didn't pass the cookie to the website. 
But thanks a lot to Subject for providing me the functions. It gave me an idea to use those and the offered header with a JSDOM. So here is the code which worked for me:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

var stores = ["68357"];

function dataCookieToString(dataCookie) {
    var t = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < dataCookie.length; x++) {
        t += ((t !== "") ? "; " : "") + dataCookie[x].key + "=" + dataCookie[x].value;
    }
    return t;
}

function mkdataCookie(cookie) {
    var t, j;
    cookie = cookie.toString().replace(/,([^ ])/g, ",[12],$1").split(",[12],");
    for (var x = 0; x < cookie.length; x++) {
        cookie[x] = cookie[x].split("; ");
        j = cookie[x][0].split("=");
        t = {
            key: j[0],
            value: j[1]
        };
        for (var i = 1; i < cookie[x].length; i++) {
            j = cookie[x][i].split("=");
            t[j[0]] = j[1];
        }
        cookie[x] = t;
    }
    return cookie;
}

var dataCookie = mkdataCookie('MC_STORE_ID=' + stores[0] + '; Expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86409000));

jsdom.env({
    url: 'http://www.example.de',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': "NodeJS/1.0",
            'Cookie': dataCookieToString(dataCookie)
    },
    scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'],
    done: function (err, window) {
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        console.log($('body').html());
    }
});
```

The cookie was set succsessfuly and I got the webpages source code for this very branch I wanted.
Thank you for the answers and hope it would help someone else.

Comment: 'Both answers' is an ephemeral statement. Here in 2020 it takes quite a bit of work to discover which two answers you were referring to.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from array of cookies (coming from set-cookie header from response) to a request cookie:

```
    headers: {
     'cookie':cookies.map(c=>c.substr(0, c.indexOf(";"))).reduce((a, b) => a + "; " + b)
}
```