# How do I send HTTP request with cookie by NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, web-development-server

I want to send a HTTP POST request with cookie by NodeJS,
to simulate the behavior of the following "curl" command:

[Notice: here is HTTPS not HTTP]

```
curl -v --header "Referer: https://some-domain.com/accounts/login/" --cookie csrftoken=xxxxxssometokenxxxxx --data 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=xxxxxssometokenxxxxx&username=tom.rock&password=somepassword' https://some-domain.com/
```

My current code like following, but I always get **403**:

```
var request = require("request");
var querystring = require('querystring');

process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
var endpoint = "https://some-domain.com/";
var username = "tom.rock";
var password = "somepassword";
var csrftoken = "xxxxxssometokenxxxxx";  // Guarantee the token is fresh

var form = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
};

request({
        "headers": {
            "Referer": endpoint + "accounts/login/",
            "Cookie": "csrftoken=" + csrftoken
        },
        "url": endpoint,
        "body": querystring.stringify(form),
        "method": "POST"
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Here is error:");
            console.dir(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Status code is " + response.statusCode);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing cookies in NodeJs http request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365600/passing-cookies-in-nodejs-http-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 403 error, not because of cookie header but a missing content-type header. 
Modify your headers field as in this way.

```
    "headers": {
        "Referer": endpoint + "accounts/login/",
        "Cookie": "csrftoken=" + csrftoken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
```

Also add a content-length header for the length of your post payload.