# how to logged in inside website from where we need to scrape a data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I need to scrape some data from website. Website have login form in which i have to logged in using node request package for scraping it. I am keep trying to login but it doesn't allow me. The code which i am using for login is :

```
var j = request.jar();
  request = request.defaults({ jar : j })
                request({
                uri:url,
                method:"POST",
                form: {UserName:"myuser1",Password:"pass1"}
                },  function (error, response, html) {
                  console.log("Status is : " + response.statusCode);
                  // console.log(response);
                  // console.log(html);
                  if (!error && response.statusCode == 302) {
                    console.log(html);
                  request.get('sub_URL',  function (error, response, html) {
                    console.log("Inner URL status is : " + response.statusCode);
                    // console.log(response);
                  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(html);
                  }
                  });
                  }
                  else{
                    console.log("sdfsfasdgsdfgsdfgdfghghghghdfgdfgsd");
                  }
                });
```

I have seen some websites and also github references but it doesn't work.
Please help me!!!

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: What error it gives

Comment: it is not giving any error but it gives me html of unknown page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run it in desktop only, I'd suggest nightmare.js or phantom.js which allows you to programmatically open login model and enter text input.
The problem you might facing is:

1. login screen is a iframe, frame makes scraping data complicated but
   it's taken cared in different frameworks by switching to the child
   frame like switchToFrame('child_frame')
2. website requires you enter a confirmation code from water mark, then you have no way of getting that. In this case you will have to
   use cookie injection. Now it become a bit of grey zone, if it's ok
   to do it (I personally don't know how to determine that), you just
   get an chrome extension to view cookies, and export it to a json
   file, then use proper method from frameworks to inject them all.
3. website requires confirmation code from google auth or sort. yea I never messed with those big guys, so I don.

Comment: that means, there is no way of login in using the code i used above.

Comment: well, there're people trying to set the "Cookie" header in a request, but so far I haven't seen a working example. I tried once and it was rejected, but you can give it a shot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365600/passing-cookies-in-nodejs-http-request

Comment: i didn't get the link but i m trying to login with nightmare js but it is giving me this error : Error occured : Can't find npm module 'electron'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?

Comment: you probably did some dependency wrong, try to start a new project and run sample code for their tutorial first.