# Node.js - How to set cookies on http request

Tags: node.js, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365600/passing-cookies-in-nodejs-http-request) but couldn't get it to work. I make a jQuery ajax request to log in to a Drupal system with `xhrFields` `withCredentials` set to true. Server returns the session name and id. So I guess my question is; how would I set those `withCredentials` with `request` as it is done with ajax call?

```
var cookie = request.cookie(app.session.sessionName + '=' + app.session.sessionId);

progress(request(url), {
    header: {
        'Cookie': cookie
    }
})

// Access denied [Anonymous user]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the header does not work but I found the solution (which was actually in the [docs](https://github.com/request/request));

```
var request = require('request');
var j = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie(app.session.sessionName + '=' + app.session.sessionId);
j.setCookie(cookie, url);

request({url: url, jar: j})
//....
```

Later you can see the cookie on `end` event;

```
//var cookie_string = j.getCookieString(url);
//console.log('Cookie: ', cookie_string);
```